# How to use WordPress metaquery when meta_value is saved as serialized key/value

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization, metadata, meta-query

I am Working on WordPress project , which required me to manipulate the existing plugin's **WP_Query**

On the front-end side , I have 3 Dropdown , in which 2 of them I have customizes with **tax_query** and using plugin's **filter** , I don't know how to customize with **meta_query** ( check screenshot )

[image]

```
<?php 
add_filter( 'learndash_ld_course_list_query_args', 'filter__learndash_ld_course_list_query_args', 10, 2 );
function filter__learndash_ld_course_list_query_args( $filter, $atts ) {

    if ( ! isset( $filter['tax_query'] ) ) {
        $filter['tax_query'] = array();
    }
    if ( ! isset( $filter['meta_query'] ) ) {
        $filter['meta_query'] = array();
    }
    if ( isset( $_GET['catid'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['catid'] ) ) { 
        $filter['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'ld_course_category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => intval( $_GET['catid'] ),
        );
    }
    if ( isset( $_GET['taxid'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['taxid'] ) ) { 
        $filter['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy' => $atts['course_taxonomy'],
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => intval( $_GET['taxid'] ),
        );
    }
    if ( isset( $_GET['priceid'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['priceid'] ) ) { 
        $filter['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key'       => '_sfwd-courses',
            'value'     => '',
            'compare'   => 'LIKE',
        );
    }
    if ( count( $filter['tax_query'] ) > 1 ) {
        $filter['tax_query']['relation'] = 'AND';
    }

    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($filter);
    return $filter;
}
```

But I am stuck in **meta_query** , because it stores data in **serialize** array ( Check screenshots )

[image]

What should I write here to compare **`'value'     => '',`** ??

Comment: You’re gonna have to use the LIKE operator and %…% around the value, to find a partial match. As for _what_ to match - well, just `free` or `"free"` might not be a good idea, because then you would get false positives, if any of the _other_ properties in that serialized array could ever contain `free` as well. So you should probably include the key here as well - but then you will have to include the part in between as well, and that means the `s:4` part needs to be made dynamic as well.

Comment: It is not only `free` , it is depend on `$_GET['priceid']` like :  `open` , `close` ... so likewise  `s:4` will also change ?

Comment: Yes, the `s:4` here means that the following value is of a string type, and has a length of 4. So for `close` instead of `free`, that part of the string will be `s:5:"close"` instead then.

Comment: I got your point , but it seems like static , and I have to make it inside many `if` condition.
but Yes , I think this is the only solution ..  let me try this

Comment: Then determine the length of the value you actually got in `$_GET['priceid']`, and then _insert_ that number dynamically …

Comment: Yes , Great Idea... You can post this answer in the answer box , I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re gonna have to use the LIKE operator <del>and %…% around the value</del> (actually, with WP_Query you don’t need to insert that yourself, with the operator set to `LIKE`, WP will automatically put the `%…%` around the value itself), to find a partial match. As for what to match - just `%free%` or `%"free"%` might not be a good idea, because then you would get false positives, if any of the other properties in that serialized array could ever contain `free` as well.

So you should probably include the key here as well - but then you will have to include the part in between as well, and that means the `s:4` part needs to be made dynamic as well. What the number needs to be, can easily be determined by `strlen($_GET['priceid'])`